# How do you apply a material to selected faces in Maya using Python?

Tags: python, maya

I'm creating a tool for a homework assignment to create and apply materials to selected faces of target objects.  The idea is that you'll be able to select faces, type in a name, pick a colour, and it will create and apply the material to the selected faces/objects in your scene.  I can't quite figure out how to apply the material to the selected faces though...

So far I've created the material, created a shading group for the material, connected the material to the shading group, and changed the colour.  I'm pretty new to scripting with python, so I'm having a hard time finding which command of many will actually apply my new material to my selected faces.

```py
#create a shader (material)
shader=cmds.shadingNode('blinn', asShader=True, n="Wood") #placeholder name
#create a shading group
shading_group=cmds.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True)
#connect the shader to the shading group
cmds.connectAttr('%s.outColor' %shader, '%s.surfaceShader'%shading_group)
#Change the colour
cmds.setAttr(shader+'.color', R,G,B) #replace r,g,b with values between 0 and 1
selected= cmds.ls(sl=True)
```

All of my current code works so far, but I don't know what command to use to apply the material to my selection.

I've so far looked at cmds.hyperShade, cmds.setAttr, and cmds.sets but I don't know what to make of what my console is spitting out

Comment: Could you please include any attempt you have made to solve this problem?

Comment: I've tried cmds.hyperShade("Wood", apply=True)
cmds.setAttr(selected, e=True, mat="Wood")
neither work...  I was hoping for some clue as to where to look to solve this as I'm rather new to scripting.

Edit:trying the cmds.sets command

Comment: the command hyperShade is wrongly documented, you should write mds.hyperShade( apply='Wood'). Anyway, hypershade has limitations in my memory and you should use cmds.sets

Answer (score 1):

from my other post : [How can I perform shader assignment to a geo efficiently and non-destructively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236130/how-can-i-perform-shader-assignment-to-a-geo-efficiently-and-non-destructively/57246797#57246797)

You can use cmds.sets to assign shader

```
selection = cmds.ls(sl=True, o=True)[0]    
faces = cmds.ls(sl=True)
x = 0
# assign shader
sha = cmds.shadingNode('lambert', asShader=True, name="{}_{}_lambert".format(selection, x))
sg = cmds.sets(empty=True, renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True,  name="{}_{}_sg".format(selection, x))
cmds.connectAttr( sha+".outColor", sg+".surfaceShader", f=True)
cmds.sets(faces, e=True, forceElement=sg)
```

Comment: What's the " x= 0" for in line 3?  say I want to be able to apply the material to faces regardless of how many objects said selected faces are on?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards using the cmds.sets command!  It worked!

Comment: Ive just adapted the code from a previous answer where i needed to generate several shaders. Instead of rewriting, i just put x=0 so it wont throw you an error. Feel free to remove it and change names

Comment: also if it solved your problem don't forget to mark the question as good :)

Comment: I have :D it's just I'm so new that it doesn't count visibly yet